# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Chart Helper display Legend

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, mschart

Is there any way to display legend on chart using chart helper?

It is not displaying it by default, there is no property i can say to display and if i specify legend in xml :

```
<Legends>
    <Legend _Template_=""All"" BackColor=""Black"" Docking=""Bottom"" Font=""Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"" LegendStyle=""Row"" >
    </Legend>
  </Legends>
```

It is also not working.

There is method in chart helper `public Chart AddLegend(string title = null, string name = null)`; but when i am calling it i can't see not the legend on my chart, chart not displaying as well.

```
Chart chart = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 120, height: 300, theme: chartStyle: ChartTheme.Green.ToString()) 
                .AddLegend("title", "name") // not existed legends, that's why error.
                .AddSeries(
                    chartType: "Column"
                    legend: "Rainfall"
                    xValue: new[] { "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may" },
                    yValues: new[] { "20", "20", "40", "10", "10" });
```

.Getting error: `Series 'Series1' uses non-existing legend name 'Rainfall'. Set Legend property value to Default`

If i change `legend: "Rainfall"` to `legend: "Default"` getting same error.

How could i make this legend name existed? For example in case of using `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` directly it will be looking like that:

```
        chart.Legends.Add("Legend1");

        // show legend based on check box value
        chart.Legends["Legend1"].Enabled = true;
```

But how to achieve the same thing with helper?

Answer (score 11):

You need to give each Series a name, then call the AddLegend() with no parameters to add the Legend.

```
    var chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 250)
        .AddSeries(
            chartType: "column",
            xValue: new [] { 2010, 2011, 2012 },
            yValues: new[] { 100, 125, 150 },
            name: "Forecasts")
        .AddSeries(
            chartType: "column",
            xValue: new[] { 2010, 2011, 2012 },
            yValues: new[] { 200, 225, 250 },
            name: "Actuals")
        .AddLegend();
```